# Input custom attribute value : retrieve and loop in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, input, foreach

When I click on buttons I generate some inputs field with custom attributes like that :

```
<input type='text' name='field["+ i++ +"]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='text' name='field["+ i++ +"]' value='' data-kind='video' />
<input type='text' name='field["+ i++ +"]' value='' data-kind='text' />
```

I retrieve the 'name' value with a foreach loop in PHP :

```
$result = array_combine($num, $records);

    foreach ($result as $rank => $content)
    {
        $data = array(
            'content' => $content,
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'rank' => $rank,
            'type' => $this->input->post('field_type') // HERE
            );
                echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
    }
```

To get the 'type' I do a `$this->input->post('field_type');` which is given by this :

```
var field_type = $(":input[data-kind]").attr('data-kind');
$("#field_type").val(field_type' ');
```

and :

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="field_type" name="field_type" value="" />';
```

But it only returns me the last 'data-kind' value not each one :/

**Now i just need to loop the 'data-kind' value for each input fields and retrieve them in my foreach loop**

Any help would be very very appreciated !!

---

Many thanks for your answers, it helped me a lot! But now how can I add the result in my current foreach at 'type' data :

```
$result = array_combine($num, $records);

    foreach ($result as $rank => $content)
    {
        $data = array(
            'content' => $content,
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'rank' => $rank,
            'type' => // HERE I NEED EACH ATTRIBUTE VALUE
            );
                echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place all of the `data-kind` values in the `#field_type` field, you need something like this:

```
var fieldTypes = [];
$("input[data-kind]").each(function()
{
    fieldTypes.push( $(this).attr('data-kind') );
});
$("#field_type").val(fieldTypes.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've missed the plus sign?
`$("#field_type").val(field_type' ');`
should be `$("#field_type").val(field_type+' ');`

Answer (score 0):

This code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PKgkU/17/

Does what you want!

```
$('input').each(function(el) {
    switch ($(this).data('kind')) {
    case "video":
        kind = 'video';
        break;
    case "image":
        kind = 'image';
        break;
    case "title":
        kind = 'title';
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    $(this).after('<input type="hidden" id="field_type" name="field_type" value="' + kind + '" />');
});
```